# Name of this plug and other end needed

Tags: plug

[image: .]

can someone tell me what type of connector this is and what would be the name of the other end connecting to this

Comment: have you looked at the picture before you posted it? ... there is no reason why your finger should be in focus and the plug out of focus

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be one of the **Molex MiniFit Jr** range, which comes in various sizes, retaining mechanisms, and number of connectors.

You'll have to take some measurements to be sure, and better photos would help a lot.